# Refactoring Fat ActiveRecord Model, What Now?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, refactoring

I've been using CodeClimate to improve my code base and I have a model class that is falling down on 'definition outside of methods' and 'total overall complexity' for those that don't use CodeClimate the definition outside of methods refers to class definitions like associations and validations. And total overall complexity is what it says, ie non of my individual methods are too complex to overall the class is to complex.

Now I appreciate this could be a false position, but that D class on my score is annoying and there may well be more I can do to improve this class, so my question is:

**What if anything should I do to simplify this ActiveRecord class?**

My main problem is I've exhausted all the written about ways to refactor a fat model, using this article http://blog.codeclimate.com/blog/2012/10/17/7-ways-to-decompose-fat-activerecord-models/ and similar, I am basically left with:

- scopes x2
- attr_accessible x2
- carrierwave mount x1
- validators x4
- associations x16
- accepts_nested_attributes_for x1
- hooks eg after_save x3
- methods with some calculations of various other attribute to make my views more semantic and easier to understand
- methods around associations, handling empty associations, merging associations

Its a closed source project, but given the lack of domain logic in this class I've shared it here. https://gist.github.com/msaspence/5317419

Comment: So you can trick the software by putting the code in modules and then including the modules into your class, you will get an A form an webpage and then you will be happy? I feel that class is not complex at all, in a real world app, model classes get even more complex, I would prefer to invest my time in testing code and do refactoring when I really need it, and not when a page says my class is bad programmed based on its automated rules.

Comment: That was my feeling, but I wanted to check with people who may know better than me whether there was anything extra I could do to the class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Callbacks are hell. I mean, they are useful but they quickly overload your models.

Do you have an action in your controller to handle the unpublish thing?

If so (which I hope), this could be moved / extracted to a service object:

```
after_save :email_author_if_first_published
def email_author_if_first_published
  if pending_was == true && pending == false
  self.create_activity key: 'action.publish'
  delay.send_action_published_email
end
end

def send_action_published_email
  ActionAuthorMailer.action_published(self, self.user).deliver
end
```

---

This should not belong to the model, some presenter should be better:

```
def mixpanel_data_points
  {
    campaign_id: campaign_id,
    cause_id: cause_id
  }
end

def open_graph_type
  'campaign_action'
end

def facebook_invite_message
  "Please help me raise awareness on PatientsCreate. It'll take you 5 seconds and could create genuine change. Thanks"
end

def percentage_completed
  v = (participation_count.to_f/participation_target_count.to_f)*100
  v > 100.0 ? 100.0 : v
end
```

---

This seems not good:

```
after_update :update_campaing_actions_count
def update_campaing_actions_count
  Campaign.decrement_counter(:actions_count, self.campaign_id_was)
  Campaign.increment_counter(:actions_count, self.campaign_id)
end
```

Because you do this even if campaign_id was not changed

---

This looks bad:

```
def url
  open_graph_url "/actions/#{id}"
end
```

---

Can't tell much more, I don;t really know what is sheer data or presentation in the other methods

Comment: This is really helpful thanks, I know the url method on a model is typically bad, the reason I have it is my model is its a gem shared between two app, one links to the other but of course has no idea of the routes. Since this is actually more of a uri and a therefore a kind of id and fixed I figured it belonged in the model. Maybe there s a better way?

Comment: no obvious solution but make it clear in the code that there is a url to maintain. Imagin you chnage the routes in the other app, you'all grep for `actions_path`, and won't find `"/actions/#{id}"`